# What does this code print? Fork in loop

Tags: c, fork

I am studying for a test and doing an old assignment. I am supposed to tell what is written out by this program:

```
#include <... .h>
int g = 0;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int var = 0;
    pid_t pid;
    while (++var < 7)
        if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
            perror("fork error");
            exit(1);
        } else if (pid == 0) {
            var+=2;
        } else {
            g++;
            var++;
            if (waitpid(pid, NULL, 0) != pid) {
                perror("waitpid error");
                exit(1);
            }
       }
       printf("mypid = %d parentpid = %d var = %d g = %d\n",
              getpid(), getppid(), var, g);
       exit(0);
}
```

What I have problems to understand is when the child is calling fork. If a child call fork here will it proceed into the pid == 0 or the else statment? I would be glad if someone could give a thoroughly explanation of the answer.(I've access to the answer if anyone needs it.) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add the proper prototypes and run it. The program is well-defined, but the specific pids you get are not predictable. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce18e7ebc0710f92

Comment: The scheduling of the tasks is not predictable either. There's no way to know whether the child or parent will run first.

Comment: What? I know the answer, I am not looking for the answer. I am looking for an explanation on how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here's what's gonna happen.
The Root Parent process will fork a few times itself, and will wait until each child runs it's course before printing that "mypid=... blah blah" statement. And the children themselves will fork a few times. So, to keep things easy to follow, I'm gonna abstract the PIDs as ROOT for original process, C1, C2... for its child processes, and C1.1, C1.2, C2.1, etc for children of children.

The order in which processes/statements will run will be:

```
ROOT (++var=1<7?true) <- FORK()
C1   (var+=2=>3)
C1   printf(mypid=C1, ppid=root, g=0, v=3)
C1   (++var=4<7?true) <- FORK()
C1.1 (var+=2=>6)
C1.1 printf (C1.1, C1, g=0, v=6)
C1.1 (++var=7<7?false)
C1.1 END
C1   (g++=1,v++=5) <- This could happen either before or after c1.1 ends but I'm just treating it as if it happens after the WAIT.
C1   printf (C1, root, g=1, v=5)
C1   (++var=6<7?true) <- FORK()
C1.2 (var+=2=>8)
C1.2 printf(C1.2, C1, g=1, v=8)
C1.2 (++var=9<7?false)
C1.2 END
C1   (g++=2, v++=7)
C1   printf(C1, root, g=2, v=7)
C1   (++var=8<7?false)
C1   END
ROOT (g++=1, v++=2)
ROOT printf(R,0,1,2)
ROOT (++var=3<7?true) <- FORK()
C2   (var+=2=>5)
C2   printf(C2, R, g=1, v=5)
C2   (++var = 6<7?true) <- FORK()
C2.1 (var+=2=>8)
C2.1 printf(C2.1, C2, g=1, v=8)
C2.1 (++var=9<7?false)
C2.1 END
C2   (g++=2, v++=7)
C2   printf(C2, R, 2, 7)
C2   (++var=8<7?false)
C2   END
ROOT (g++=2, v++=4)
ROOT printf(R,0,2,4)
ROOT (++var=5<7?true) <- FORK()
C3   (var+=2=>7)
C3   printf(C3, R, 2, 7)
C3   (++var=8<7?false)
C3   END
ROOT (g++=3, v++=6)
ROOT printf(R,0,3,6)
ROOT (++var=7<7?false)
ROOT END
```

So, the output would be: (Formatted as MyPid, ParentPid, G, VAR)

```
C1,   ROOT, 0, 3
C1.1, C1,   0, 6
C1,   ROOT, 1, 5
C1.2, C1,   1, 8
C1,   ROOT, 2, 7
ROOT, 0,    1, 2
C2,   ROOT, 1, 5
C2.1, C2,   1, 8
C2,   ROOT, 2, 7
ROOT, 0,    2, 4
C3,   ROOT, 2, 7
ROOT, 0,    3, 6
```

Hopefully, I got that answer right :) And hopefully my method of explaining was clear enough.

g and var are both tracked separately inside each process, however they get their values from their parent process's current state.

Cheers!

Comment: shouldn't the C1.1 run one more time because before the (++var...) it's 6. So 6 < 7, and then increment so it's 7 while in the loop?

Comment: It's a ++var, and not a var++. pre-increment vs post-increment... so, it actually pre-increments and then compares the value of 7, not 6 and then post-increment it to 7. Does that make sense?

Comment: It would be nice if you could accept my answer... provided it was correct ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you call a fork the child process is created and hence now you have both parent process and as well child process running parallel. doesn't know in which order they execute.
consider child executes first and then parent.now the child process will get a pid == 0; hence the child execute its part of the program that's created and execute `var +=2;`. then the parent execute its part of the program where it will wait for the child process to get exit and later parent exits under condition if parent executes first or else the child executes and give its status to parent upon which the parent exits after child exits.

Comment: You have some good information in your answer, but it is almost totally lost in what reads like a 'stream of consciousness run-on sentence'. The information would be much more helpful if formatted in a way that is readable. Take time with your answer.

Comment: I am confused as to what happens when the child runs, it will create another child. Does the child become a parent because it used fork?

Comment: parent create child and you see only these two process running. you will have no more process in the memory.@Fjodor